# How length is description of product in Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop

I pasted a HTML into my description in product. When I look at website the content is cut. How much data I can storage in product description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a description as long as you want in Prestashop. I think your problem is linked to the HTML cleanup made by TinyMCE Editor. You will have to check the source code form the description field to check if all of your data is here. If you included iframe, it cannot work. You will have to enable iframes in content in general settings.